# Contour Integral over an Ellipse

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, contour-integration

> Compute the integral $$\oint_C \frac{2z - 1}{z^2 - z}$$

[image]

So I believe Cauchy's integral theorem does not apply here since the function is not analytic at zero. Im not quite sure how to find the parametrisation of the ellipse though when we only know the foci since there is no labelling of the exact position of the vertices. Im not sure if they want us to guess their position, or there is something Im missing?

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Use Residue Theorem.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy We haven't learned about the residue theorem yet in class. I think the intention is to use a parametrisation and compute in the normal way with partial fractions. Could be a badly written problem though with how they sketched the curve C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can evaluate the integral using Cauchy's Integral formula for the function $f(z)=2z-1$. For this write the integral as $\int_C \frac {2z-1} {z-1}dz-\int_C\frac {2z-1} {z}dz$. The first integral is $2\pi i f(1)$ and the second one is $2\pi i  f(0)$.

Comment: Can I ask what the reasoning is behind the splitting of the integral?

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all, the function has a second order pole at zero. So, the first concept you need to understand to solve these kinds of problems is zeros and poles. Then you can use it to understand how residues of a function can be calculated at a pole.

Then you should be more or less ready to learn Cauchy's residue theorem.

Using this theorem, you wont need the parametrization of the ellipse, since the only thing needed to use the theorem is that the curve you are integrating over is closed.

Comment: I will have a look at Cauchy's residue theorem. Looks like there is a pole at both $z=1$ and $z = 0$ though? The problem is taken from section 14.2 in Kreyzig Advanced Engineering Mathematics where we have not yet learned about the residue theorem. Might just be a bad problem though since the ellipse is not labeled that well.

Comment: @Pame I just looked at the solutions in Kreyzig. From the solutions, it looks like you are meant to use Cauchy's Integral Formula, which is introduced in the next subchapter. So, yeah, bad problem..